# open div tag and close it in another place by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible by using JavaScript to open any tag, for example div#js and insert closing tag in any place I want, like on example below?

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="js">
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
</div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to wrap some elements?

Answer (score 2):

If you start with:

```
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
<div id="third">3</div>
<div id="fourth">4</div>
```

and need to get this structure:

```
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="js">
  <div id="second">2</div>
  <div id="third">3</div>
</div>
<div id="fourth">4</div>
```

the you can use `$('#second').wrap('<div id="js"></div>').after($('#third'))`.

See demo below:

```js
$('#second').wrap('<div id="js"></div>').after($('#third'));
```

```css
#js {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
<div id="third">3</div>
<div id="fourth">4</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

As you've tagged your code jQuery, I'll answer it in that sense. If you're programmatically inserting a div element into the page with juery, like this:

```
var bodyEl = $("body");
var myJsEl = $("<div>").attr("id", "js");

bodyEl.append(myJsEl);
```

... As has been noted, the `$("<div>")` code is the functional equivalent of `document.createElement("div")`, which creates the code block, both opening and closing the DOM element. Thus, when I create the element by either approach, programmatically speaking, the close is not something I can control.

That said, in the "bad old days" of `document.write()`, we did have the option of hard-coding opening tags and neglecting to include closing tags. DON'T DO THIS! It's deprecated, it's bad form and it can create serious coding issues later.

Comment: please delete this... very low quality. `$('<div>')` is `document.createElement` jquery equivalent...

Comment: Which was sort of my point -- if the OP was asking this as a jQuery-tagged question, it seems logical to use jQuery as the answer to that question.

Comment: *it will automagically close that tag for you*... what? In your case you're creating a valid html element

Comment: And I'll be glad to edit this, to fit your comments.